# Sending the JFrame information to the Printer

Tags: java, swing, printing

The application is for pulling information to fill out a form from a database or write to the database from this form. Right now I can do both of those with using netbeans and contacting my MySQL test server that I have up and running at the moment.

The issue I am having is I need to print the information attained from the database in a form like manner rather than a table, in order to match the hand written forms we are currently using at the office. Is there a way to print the entire JFrame or all the contents in the JFrame just as they are laid out on the screen for the user to see?

Everything that I have seen thus far will print either a region of the screen (text box) or print it via a table.

The application will be compiled for both Linux and Windows when all is said and done.

Code:

```
package Information;

import java.awt.print.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HATDB extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Printable {

    JFrame frameToPrint;

    /** Creates new form HATDB */
    public HATDB() {
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
        PrinterException {

        if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
         * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
         */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        /* Now print the window and its visible contents */
        frameToPrint.printAll(g);

        /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public HATDB(JFrame f) {
        frameToPrint = f;
    }

    private void OK_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        //job.setPrintable();
        boolean ok = job.printDialog();
        if (ok) {
            try {
                job.print();
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Print UI Example");
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new HATDB().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can print a JFrame similar to printing other Java components, but it is not optimized for creating pretty print outs. Why not instead simply use a reporting tool such as JasperReports as this type of program was created to solve just this sort of problem?

Comment: Are there any examples or direction you can point me in for using JasperReports?

Comment: Um... I guess Google must be down?

Comment: I didn't know if there was any specific examples that you have come across in the past that were good and that you would recommend. Of course i have already been looking them up, but if someone can show good examples then why re-find those good examples?

Answer (score 3):

From the [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) API: "J2SE 5 adds methods to `JTable` to provide convenient access to some common printing needs. Simple new [`print()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#print%28%29) methods allow for quick and easy addition of printing support to your application." These methods print all the rows in your `TableModel`, rather than just those rows that are visible.

Addendum: You can print exactly what's on the screen, as shown in [*Printing the Contents of a User Interface*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/gui.html), or you can print the entire contents of the `TableModel`, as shown [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/swing.html) and in [*Chapter 6 Continued: Advanced Printing*](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/advprint.html).

Addendum: Here's an example that prints a `JPanel` with a  `JTree`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192204 */
public class PrintTest extends JPanel implements Printable {

    public PrintTest() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        JTree tree = new JTree();
        this.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
            tree.expandRow(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int i) throws PrinterException {
        if (i > 0) {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
        PrintTest.this.printAll(g);
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                final PrintTest pt = new PrintTest();
                f.add(pt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                JButton b = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Print") {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                        PageFormat pf = pj.pageDialog(pj.defaultPage());
                        pj.setPrintable(pt, pf);
                        if (pj.printDialog()) {
                            try {
                                pj.print();
                            } catch (PrinterException pe) {
                                pe.printStackTrace(System.err);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                JPanel p = new JPanel();
                p.add(b);
                f.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I can do simple printing (printing contents of a text box or a table, but not the entire form). The issue i am having is that I am trying to print the form as seen on the screen. That is not working.

Comment: I've added links for both approaches above.

Comment: I have added the code as explained above but i am not sure if it is right or not (i'm a little new to java...) I am not sure how to post a file on here so i am uploading a simple mock up of the program.

Comment: .form (http://www.megaupload.com/?d=41V55V2V)

Those are the 2 files from the netbeans application....

Comment: This is going to probably sound dumb but what do you want for the sscce? or how do i generate it from the code that i have from netbeans?

Comment: [`PrintUIWindow`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/examples/PrintUIWindow.java) from the tutorial mentioned above is such an example.

Comment: Here is what i came up with i hope it is a little more of what you are looking for... I left it in .java formatting. This is the code that i used for the printing and nothing else (the working bits ie database look-up). I just simply used the OK button to print.

http://www.megaupload.com/?d=4JUJXYM2

Comment: Just to clarify the issue... when i press the button to initialize the printing the dialogue appears to prompt for printer and properties, though no exceptions are thrown or errors it passes through it just as if it had printed the file.

Comment: `megaupload.com` is _terrible_! Code pasted above.