# How to detect the ‘Save as PDF…’ was picked from an AWT PrinterJob on OS X

Tags: java, macos, swing, printing

I have the following code that shows a native print dialog in my java application.

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PrintRequestAttributeSet atts = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
atts.add(DialogTypeSelection.NATIVE);

if (job.printDialog(atts)) 
{
    PrintService newlyUsedService = job.getPrintService();
    DocPrintJob docJob = newlyUsedService.createPrintJob();
    // print the passed javax.print.SimpleDoc object.
    docJob.print(simpleDoc, atts);
}
```

This code works fine when a printer is selected and the Print button is clicked, but it does not work when the user selects any option from the “PDF” menu at the bottom left. The getPrintService method returns the last selected printer (`Lillith` from the screenshot) when one of the options in the "PDF" menu are selected.

[image: Screenshot of OS X print dialog]

Could anyone suggest what should be done to detect when “Save as PDF…” was selected in the print dialog and respond accordingly.

Comment: What does your program do when it gets the real printer, but you select "Save as PDF..."?

Comment: I get the pages printed at the printer and no pdf or postscript file saved.

Comment: @trashgod Where does that example do printing?

Comment: I tried it with both `Preview` and `Save as PDF`. Edit: I also tried with `Any printer` in the `pageDialog()`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to cite this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8192592/230513).

Comment: Well, the issue is I don't have access to an object that implements printable interface. I get a SimpleDoc object passed into the method that has the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a Print Job Listener? Just read up on it now, I hope it will be of some help:

[Print Job Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/printing.fm5.html#999518)