# Java : how to call object of parameterised constructor on a button event

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have one program PrintUI.java, which create a frame containing user's details and one print button. Clicking on print button it gives print out of that frame. Now I want to call this program on print button of another form i.e test.java.

Code for PrintUI.java is :

```
 public PrintUI(JFrame f) 
 {
    frameToPrint = f;
    //f.setVisible(true);
 }
```

And I am calling this object on event of button in test.java

The code of test.java is :

```
  Print.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            PrintUI p1=new PrintUI(f); 
            f.setVisible(true);
        } 

    });
```

It's not giving error, but it doesn't show anything. Please help me to recode this.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Now exactly how you called the constructor has been answered, in your question, but what exactly you wrote for the output to come (for printing to happen inside this class) is not shown anywhere. So please provide that.

Comment: For reference, there's a complete example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8192592/230513).

Answer (score 1):

your frame is not visible so call frame method `setVisible`()`

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I have call frame.setVisible(true) in both programs, but still it displays nothing. :(

Comment: also set the size of the frame. frame.setSize(); and call this in constructor

Comment: yup, I have tried it in constructor of Print UI. I have edited it the code.

Comment: I have done setsize,setvisible etc in main method PrintUI.java. When I run PrintUI(containging frame) its working properly. when I call this on event of button of another form i.e test.java, It doesn't display anything.

Comment: you give the refrece of f to frameToPrint.so call of setvisibility on f does ont work . try to call frameToPrint.setVisibility(true);

Comment: its giving error to frameToPrint.setVisibility(true); and prints nothing to frameToPrint.setVisible(true);

Comment: I am using netbeans and It giving error as 'can not find symbol' to method setVisibility(boolean). I have already imported the package javax.swing.JFrame

Comment: Sorry. this is setVisible().not setvisibility.

Comment: I have used setVisible(), but its doesn't affect.