# Setting to print JFrame content with thermal printer

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have written code to send a `JFrame`'s content to the laser printer. It works for me, but the same code does not work for a thermal printer. There may be a need to send some setting to the printer. It leaves much more left margin to page in thermal printer.

Comment: See also the [Q&As](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%22thermal+printer%22).

Answer (score 1):

Possible causes of the disparity you observe include these:

- physical limitation of the printer design
- defective or outdated printer driver
- incorrect implementation of the `Printable` interface

Empirically, you can attempt to `translate()` the graphics context in your `Printable` implementation, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8192592/230513). Also look for an updated driver.