# Way to send defaultlistmodel to a printer?

Tags: java, swing, printing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a homework project and it requires me to create a button that once it is clicked, it sends the defaultlistmodel data to the printer. I have everything working fine, but I just can't find a good solution to this problem. My code (so far) is this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;





import javax.print.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class i extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField jTextField;
DefaultListModel ListModel = new DefaultListModel();
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList <String>();
String str;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                i frame = new i();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public i() throws IOException {
    super("List");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    jTextField = new JTextField();
    jTextField.setBounds(15, 80, 168, 20);
    contentPane.add(jTextField);
    jTextField.setColumns(10);

    final JList jList = new JList(ListModel);
    jList.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    jList.setBounds(289, 54, 135, 197);
    contentPane.add(jList);


    JButton jButton = new JButton("Add");
    jButton.setBounds(190, 79, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(jButton);
    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String str=jTextField.getText();
            ListModel.addElement(str);
            jTextField.setText("");
            //arr.add(str);
            //System.out.println(arr);
        }
    });



    JButton delete = new JButton("DELETE");
    delete.setBounds(190, 162, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(delete);
    delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent k){
            ListModel.removeElement(jList.getSelectedValue());
        }
    });

    JButton btnUp = new JButton("UP");
    btnUp.setBounds(190, 125, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnUp);
    btnUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int index = jList.getSelectedIndex();
            if(index == -1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select something to move.");
            } else if(index > 0) {
                String temp = (String)ListModel.remove(index);
                ListModel.add(index - 1, temp);
                jList.setSelectedIndex(index -1);
            }
        }
    });

    JButton btnDown = new JButton("DOWN");
    btnDown.setBounds(190, 196, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnDown);
    btnDown.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){ 
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){ 
            int index = jList.getSelectedIndex(); 
            if( index == -1 ) 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select something to move."); 
            else if( index < ListModel.size() - 1 ){ 
                String temp = (String)ListModel.remove( index ); 
                ListModel.add( index + 1, temp ); 
                jList.setSelectedIndex( index + 1 ); 
            } 
        } 
    }); 

    JLabel lblItems = new JLabel("Items:");
    lblItems.setBounds(290, 37, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblItems);

    JButton btnSave = new JButton("SAVE");
    btnSave.setBounds(190, 228, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnSave);
    btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            try {
                FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("list.txt", true);

                PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter(fwriter);

                System.out.println("LIST: " + ListModel);

                outputfile.println("LIST: " + ListModel);
                outputfile.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println("Error in creating the file.");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    JButton btnDeleteAll = new JButton("DELETE ALL");
    btnDeleteAll.setBounds(15, 162, 168, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnDeleteAll);
    btnDeleteAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            ListModel.removeAllElements();
        }
    });

    JButton btnPrint = new JButton("PRINT");
    btnPrint.setBounds(15, 228, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnPrint);
    btnPrint.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            try {
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("");
                PrintWriter prin = new PrintWriter(stream);
                prin.println(ListModel);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                System.out.println("Error");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Any help? I'm not trying to rush, just need some help. Also, I have read the API and I'm still lost.

Comment: Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/).

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for that, I tried it and now once I open my application it asked if I want to print before the application. I'm completely stuck.

Comment: Maybe try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8192592/230513) with your `JList`?